# Preventing Gnome-Shell from constantly freezing

Tags: gnome

Whenever I move/copy/rename a file using Nautilus, or download a file using Firefox, Gnome-Shell freezes for about 5 to 10 seconds. Only the mouse is still responsive, but I can't click or manipulate anything. This is immensely frustrating. I'm seeing no explicit error messages. I'm using Ubuntu 12.10. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: This is a known problem in 12.10 that drove me nuts for a year. The problem is gone in 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is try to reload gnome by running the following command in a terminal

```
DISPLAY=:0 gnome-shell --replace
```

once you run this command you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> and you GNOME will be up and running again :)